# How to log in a user from an external page in prestashop module

Tags: php, prestashop

I am creating a module for prestashop that users are able to sign up to site from external page, so I can get user information like email and password. But how can I log in this user by created account?

The main goal is that I login user programmatically in module.

Comment: Can we see the code you've written that isn't currently working?

Comment: I didn't write this part of code !I need idea how to do this

Comment: What do you mean by the "external page". Do you want to allow users to log in from outside of your store environment? About what version of prestashop are you interested?

Comment: Yes I want allow to login from outside of web site . presta 1.6